# Limit values displayed in the select list based on the data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables:

```
Table1
___________
Location_ID
User_ID
Type_ID

UserTypes
_________
Type_ID Type_name
1111    Type1
2222    Type2
```

I am displaying the data in an Interactive Grid for a specific location, and for the User Type there is a select list that pulls data from UserTypes table:

```
SELECT Type_name d, type_id r                                                            
FROM  UserTypes
WHERE (is_active=1 OR type_id = TO_NUMBER(:type_id))
```

For each location there can be only one user of `Type1` so whenever I am adding a record to the grid, 
I want to check if a user of type `Type1` already exists for that specific location ID, so if it does, I only want to display option `Type 2` in the select list. 
How can I modify my column source to incorporate that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a solution with an `EXISTS` keyword such as below one

```
SELECT Type_name d, type_id r                                                            
  FROM  UserTypes u
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT Type_ID 
                  FROM Table1 
                 WHERE Type_ID = u.Type_ID
                   AND Type_ID = TO_NUMBER(:type_id)
                   AND Type_name = 'Type1'
                 GROUP BY Type_ID
                HAVING count(*)=1 
                )
   AND is_active=1
   AND Type_name = 'Type2';
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion and it works for the select list in a newly created row but displays Type_ID instead of Type_name in the existing rows.   Also i have to change your query to NOT EXISTS as otherwise it only displays Type1

Comment: you're welcome @CodingDuchess, reconsidered, I think I fixed by adding `AND Type_name = 'Type2'` to the main query.